# Can I use state value again in state?

Tags: reactjs

i want to use **index** value for **index_child**, but **this.state** is undefined

```
state ={
    index:0,
    index_child:this.state.index
}
```

This code also fails.

```
state ={
    index:0,
    index_child:this.index
}
```

Comment: may I know why do you want to do that?

Comment: @kiranvj index_child is an array containing other components. I want to pass the index value to props for these components.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Since you intend to have same value in `index` and `index_child`, you don't need both of them.

Comment: @estus
The index_child array can be pushed or popped if there are props changed from the parent component. The index value is the value that is being changed in the current component.
Maybe I designed the component structure incorrectly.
My project is a project that automatically slides.
index_child is the sliding page and index is the current page number.

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , so your case could be understood better. But if index and index_child are expected to differ later then set them explicitly to same value, `state ={ index:0, index_child: 0}`. If they aren't expected to differ later, you don't need two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want to do that, but you can try something like this.

```js
    this.state = {
      index:10,
      get index_child () {
        return this.index
      }
    };
    
    console.log(state);
```